# Xubuntu keeps mounting 3G usb modem as cd

Tags: xubuntu, usb-modem, 3g

I currently using Xubuntu 17.10 amd64 (installed on my harddisk).Firstly, when 3G usb modem is inserted it is mounted as cd before swith to modem mode.So I can use it to connect to the internet.I just wonder why it is mounted as cd at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

It is mounted as CD because it contains small amount of storage space. The drivers necessary for installation for different operating systems are stored there.

So it shows up as any storage device attached would show up.